# How do you obtain the OBJECT_LOCATION when uploading objects to Google Cloud?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

In Google Cloud's [docs for uploading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#uploading-an-object), they mention needing to include the `OBJECT_LOCATION`:

[image]

My question is how to obtain that value when you are dealing with a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object. The only property that seems relevant is [`webkitRelativePath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/webkitRelativePath). However, when I console log that, it just shows `<empty string>`. I figured that it's possible it just won't display it in the console so I tried just uploading it anyway, but it didn't work. The object in Google Cloud was corrupted.

```
const uploadFile = async (file: File): Promise<string> => {
  const BUCKET_NAME = "example";
  const objectName = encodeURI(file.name);
  const url = `https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/${BUCKET_NAME}/o?uploadType=media&name=${objectName}`;
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": file.type,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLOUD_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    },
    body: file.webkitRelativePath,
  }).then((response) => response.json());

  return response.selfLink;
};
```

Furthermore, I see `--data-binary` in the docs for the curl request. I'm not sure what that means when using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) though. From the research I've done it looks like what I'm doing by using `body` is correct, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we are confusing the syntax of the "curl" command for the parameters and payload of the REST request itself.  If we look at the following web page:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert

We see the REST request that must be made to upload a new object into Google Cloud Storage.  What we need to do is study THAT documentation in depth.  If we read it, we will eventually find that the payload of the REST request (i.e. the body of the POST) is supposed to contain the data that will be written into the newly created object.

Now ... using the "curl" command, we can submit HTTP requests (REST requests).  The "curl" command allows us to supply payload data as part of the request.  The curl command can *source* the data to be passed in the payload of the REST request from a local file ... it is THAT that you are seeing in the OBJECT_LOCATION.

To achieve what you want (uploading the content of a local file to GCS) then it is your responsibility to open the local file, read its content and submit that content as part of the REST request.  There is no option to supply a "local file name" in a REST request and somehow have that local file read and copied to GCS (through a REST request).  Tools like gsutil wrap that capability in command line equivalents.

Instead of building REST requests by hand I strongly suggest using the client libraries associated with each of the GCP products (including GCS).  These client libraries provide language specific high level constructs and make the underlying REST requests on your behalf behind the scenes.  Instead of trying to build REST requests yourself ... make the the client SDK calls and they will make the REST calls for you.

Comment: Hm, but the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#uploading-an-object) gives `Desktop/dog.png` as the example value for `OBJECT_LOCATION`, not the actual content of the file. Are you saying that based on how curl works, it will include the actual content of the file even though the value is `Desktop/dog.png`, and because I'm using `fetch` instead of curl, I need to do that myself?

Comment: I'm making the request from the context of a web browser. From what I was able to tell there are no client libraries for the front end, only back end. Is that true? Do you know of a client library for the front end?

Comment: Howdy Adam ... yes sir to your first question.   It is the curl command itself that is loading the content of the file to be uploaded and it is the curl command that is inserting that in the payload of the REST request.  If you are using fetch() then it becomes your responsibility to load the file's content AND supply that as the payload of the request.

Comment: Howdy Adam ... from the context of the web browser, there is indeed a client library story that can be found here:

https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client

This relies only on JavaScript and can be called from the browser platform.